# How to convert speech to text?

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I am trying to develop the following functionality.

1. The first task to convert text to voice - *DONE*
2. The second task to ***convert voice to text*** - **Getting issue**
3. The third task to implement these both on the given chat board where already AI chat is

I am using following code to get the text from voice/speech.
I am getting the result but is not proper which I want.
Please check below code snippet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace StartingWithSpeechRecognition
{
    class Program
    {
        static SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = null;
        static ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Console.WriteLine("To recognize speech, and write 'test' to the console, press 0");
            Console.WriteLine("To recognize speech and make sure the computer speaks to you, press 1");
            Console.WriteLine("To emulate speech recognition, press 2");
            Console.WriteLine("To recognize speech using Choices and GrammarBuilder.Append, press 3");
            Console.WriteLine("To recognize speech using a DictationGrammar, press 4");
            Console.WriteLine("To get a prompt building example, press 5");
            ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
            char keychar = pressedKey.KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed '{0}'", keychar);
            switch (keychar)
            {
                case '0':
                    RecognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole();
                    break;
                case '1':
                    RecognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou();
                    break;
                case '2':
                    EmulateRecognize();
                    break;
                case '3':
                    SpeechRecognitionWithChoices();
                    break;
                case '4':
                    SpeechRecognitionWithDictationGrammar();
                    break;
                case '5':
                    PromptBuilding();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You didn't press 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
            }
            if (keychar != '5')
            {
                manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
            }
            if (_recognizer != null)
            {
                _recognizer.Dispose();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        #region Recognize speech and write to console
        static void RecognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole()
        {
            _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("test"))); // load a "test" grammar
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("exit"))); // load a "exit" grammar
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole_SpeechRecognized; // if speech is recognized, call the specified method
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += _recognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole_SpeechRecognitionRejected; // if recognized speech is rejected, call the specified method
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input to the default audio device
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous

        }
        static void _recognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == "test")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test");
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
            {
                manualResetEvent.Set();
            }
        }
        static void _recognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Speech rejected. Did you mean:");
            foreach (RecognizedPhrase r in e.Result.Alternates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    " + r.Text);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Recognize speech and make sure the computer speaks to you (text to speech)
        static void RecognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou()
        {
            _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("hello computer"))); // load a "hello computer" grammar
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou_SpeechRecognized; // if speech is recognized, call the specified method
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += _recognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input to the default audio device
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous
        }
        static void _recognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == "hello computer")
            {
                SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                speechSynthesizer.Speak("hello user");
                speechSynthesizer.Dispose();
            }
            manualResetEvent.Set();
        }
        static void _recognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Alternates.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No candidate phrases found.");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Speech rejected. Did you mean:");
            foreach (RecognizedPhrase r in e.Result.Alternates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    " + r.Text);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Emulate speech recognition
        static void EmulateRecognize()
        {
            _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("emulate speech"))); // load "emulate speech" grammar
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _emulateRecognize_SpeechRecognized;

            _recognizer.EmulateRecognize("emulate speech");

        }
        static void _emulateRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == "emulate speech")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speech was emulated!");
            }
            manualResetEvent.Set();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Speech recognition with Choices and GrammarBuilder.Append
        static void SpeechRecognitionWithChoices()
        {
            _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            grammarBuilder.Append("I"); // add "I"
            grammarBuilder.Append(new Choices("like", "dislike")); // load "like" & "dislike"
            grammarBuilder.Append(new Choices("dogs", "cats", "birds", "snakes", "fishes", "tigers", "lions", "snails", "elephants")); // add animals
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(grammarBuilder)); // load grammar
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += speechRecognitionWithChoices_SpeechRecognized;
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set input to default audio device
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech
        }

        static void speechRecognitionWithChoices_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you really " + e.Result.Words[1].Text + " " + e.Result.Words[2].Text + "?");
            manualResetEvent.Set();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Speech recognition with DictationGrammar
        static void SpeechRecognitionWithDictationGrammar()
        {
            _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("exit")));
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += speechRecognitionWithDictationGrammar_SpeechRecognized;
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }

        static void speechRecognitionWithDictationGrammar_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
            {
                manualResetEvent.Set();
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You said: " + e.Result.Text);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Prompt building
        static void PromptBuilding()
        {
            PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();

            builder.StartSentence();
            builder.AppendText("This is a prompt building example.");
            builder.EndSentence();

            builder.StartSentence();
            builder.AppendText("Now, there will be a break of 2 seconds.");
            builder.EndSentence();

            builder.AppendBreak(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));

            builder.StartStyle(new PromptStyle(PromptVolume.ExtraSoft));
            builder.AppendText("This text is spoken extra soft.");
            builder.EndStyle();

            builder.StartStyle(new PromptStyle(PromptRate.Fast));
            builder.AppendText("This text is spoken fast.");
            builder.EndStyle();

            SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synthesizer.Speak(builder);
            synthesizer.Dispose();
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

If this is the wrong way then please suggest me right way or any reference link or tutorial will be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you should be a bit more descriptive on your issue.Check the help section and the how to ask page.

Comment: _"Getting issue"_ - interesting ... and would you mind telling us what that issue _is_? ;)

Comment: See, when recognizing speech, results most probably will not be perfect. So if your expectation is perfect results - good luck. If your results don't resemble anything near an acceptable result, we maybe can help. But you need to provide us with some data ... please don't throw just some code on us expecting us to find your flaw.

Answer (score 4):

The System.Speech.Recognition is an old API.

I think you have to use Google Speech API: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics Or MS Bing speech API: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/

I preferred the Google API. And here is very small example:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
using Grpc.Auth;
using System;

    var speech = SpeechClient.Create( channel );
    var response = speech.Recognize( new RecognitionConfig()
    {
        Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
        SampleRateHertz = 16000,
        LanguageCode = "hu",
    }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile( "888.wav" ) );
    foreach ( var result in response.Results )
    {
        foreach ( var alternative in result.Alternatives )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( alternative.Transcript );
        }
    }
```

But you can find more samples:
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples

Regrads